# Adding DataGridView values when the grid displays IEnumerable list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, mvp

In a MVP win forms app, I have an `IEnumerable <Object>` list and lets say these Objects have `decimal` `properties` called `P1` and `P2`. I'm displaying this list on a DataGridView as follows...

```
public IEnumerable<Object> GridData
{
    set { dgvObjects.DataSource = value; }
}
```

But in the grid there is an additional field called `Total` and I need the total value of those `P1` and `P2` here. I'm supposed to do this in my `Presenter` class. Appreciate if you could show me how to do this properly?

**NOTE** : I could do this by adding a new property called `Total` to my `Object` class and then in a `foreach` loop I would do the addition. so that will be shown on the grid. But I feel that it would not be the best approach.!!

Also I need to show the totals of the columns down the grid or in text boxes probably placed at the bottom.

Comment: so a Total for a single row, or a Total of all rows ?

Comment: Total of all rows and also column totals...

Comment: So why hold it inside grid ? Why not just separated field (Label, say) on the form, on the bottom of the grid that shows total of all. and that total you just sum ones.